# Choropleth Map in D3 Now Failing

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a web page that reads a GeoJSON file for the California Counties and then creates a choropleth map on a SVG control based on the selections of a drop down on the HTML page. It was working in November (22nd?), but when I looked at it a few days ago it was no longer working. I can't pin down the time when it broke anymore than that. The map is of the California Board of Barbering and Cosmetology licenses. The license information is stored in a separate JSON file.

When the map is rendered it is supposed to draw a black border for the counties on a map of California using the D3 GeoProjection v2 library. It then goes from county to county filling in the polygon based on the number of licenses of the selected type.

The current error is that the entire SVG element is shaded to the highest count color, a shade of golden orange, and the county of Ventura is colored correctly, but labeled as San Diego. The reason those counties are important is that they are the last two in the dataset for the color values. First San Diego and then Ventura. The area outside of Ventura county is labeled as Ventura county.

Here is the meaty part of the code:

```
    async function drawCountys(projection){
        //If lines already exist remove them
        d3.selectAll("g")
            .remove();
    
        counties = await d3.json("scripts/California_Counties.geojson");
    
        d3.select("#bbc_ca").append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(counties.features)
            .enter()
            
            .append("path")
    
            .attrs({
                    d: d3.geoPath().projection(projection),
                    stroke: "#000000",
                    fill:(d)=> {return whichColor(d.properties.id, compareField);}
            })
            .append("title")
                .text(function(d) 
                //Add a template to serve as a tooltip. Another method is to add a mouseover and mouseout event listener
                    {   let countyID = d.properties.id;
                        //Matches the value of the drop down
                        return `County: ${d.properties.Name}
    Total: ${getValue(countyID, "All").toLocaleString()}
    Barber: ${getValue(countyID, "Barber").toLocaleString()}
    Cosmetologist: ${getValue(countyID, "Cosmetologist").toLocaleString()}
    Electrologist: ${getValue(countyID, "Electrologist").toLocaleString()}
    Esthetician: ${getValue(countyID, "Esthetician").toLocaleString()}
    Manicurist: ${getValue(countyID, "Manicurist").toLocaleString()}
    Establishment: ${getValue(countyID, "Establishment").toLocaleString()}
    Mobile Unit: ${getValue(countyID, "Mobile Unit").toLocaleString()}`;
                    });
        }
```

Any help for fixes or troubleshooting, really any constructive comments, would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `d3-selection-multi`?

Comment: Yes I am. I only have these imports: d3.v5, d3-queue.v3, d3-scale-chromatic.v1, d3-geo-projection.v2, d3-selection-multi.v1

I should mention I have tried this in Firefox on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04, Chrome on Windows 10, and Chrome on an iPhone.